# Why does Swashbuckle append a version postfix to all my routes?

Tags: iis, swashbuckle

I followed the Swashbuckle installation manual for IIS hosted APIs. I installed the NuGet package and deployed it on the IIS. The documentation is now available. However all URLs are postfixed with "-v1", for example "/api/v1/myresource-v1()".

As a consequence, IIS complaint that there is no route for this URL. "/api/v1/myresource" would be correct.

Why does this happen and how do I remove this postfix for all routes?

Thank you.

Comment: That is strange! can you provide a link to a project that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Here i have mine: http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct solution for this problem but this workaround works for me:

```
c.MultipleApiVersions((apiDesc, targetApiVersion) =>
    {
        // remove any Version text from the tags                   
        apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName = Regex.Replace(apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, @"v([\d]+)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // remove -vX() from Controller Names relativ path
        apiDesc.RelativePath = Regex.Replace(apiDesc.RelativePath, @"(-v[\d]+\(\))", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // replace the relative Path Apiverision with the current api version
        apiDesc.RelativePath = Regex.Replace(apiDesc.RelativePath, @"(v[{]+version[}])", targetApiVersion, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var apiParameterDescription = apiDesc.ParameterDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "version");
        if (apiParameterDescription != null)
        { 
            apiDesc.ParameterDescriptions.Remove(apiParameterDescription);
        }

        // now filter out any controllers that aren't the target version
        var controllerNamespace = apiDesc.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.FullName;

        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(controllerNamespace, $".{targetApiVersion}.", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0 &&
        apiDesc.RelativePath.Contains($"{targetApiVersion}/");
    },
    vc =>
        {
            vc.Version("v4", "Api V4");
            vc.Version("v3", "Api V3");
            vc.Version("v2", "Api V2");
            vc.Version("v1", "Api V1");
        }
);
```